# OTRS Initial creator of a ticket

Tags: themes, otrs

Is it possible in OTRS (version 3.1, 3.2 or 3.3) to display the initial creator of a ticket in the customer overview (CustomerTicketOverview.dtl) or in the details (CustomerTicketZoom.dtl) page? For example if I create a ticket as an agent I would like to show the agents name, otherwise if the customer created that ticket then I would like to show the customers name.

I tried this:

```
$Text{"$QData{"FromRealname","60"}"}
```

which seems to always print the name of user who last respondent to the ticket. If the ticket is new it contains the name of the customer if the customer created it or if it was a telephone ticket, otherwise if it was an email ticket it seems to contain the name of the Email Address that is assigned with the queue.

```
$Text{"$Data{"CreatedBy"}"}
```

which seems to contain the id of the person who created the ticket. Is there any way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible. But you have to make a lookup to transform the UserID to an "readable" Name.

First, make a copy of Kernel/Modules/CustomerTicketZoom.pm to Custom/Kernel/Modules/CustomerTicketZoom.pm 
then modify the _mask method like so (around L#:1000):

```
    # ticket owner
if ( $Self->{Config}->{AttributesView}->{Owner} ) {
    my $OwnerName = $Self->{AgentUserObject}->UserName(
        UserID => $Param{OwnerID},
    );
    $Self->{LayoutObject}->Block(
        Name => 'Owner',
        Data => { OwnerName => $OwnerName },
    );
}
####### this is the new part #######
# ticket creator
if ( $Param{CreateBy} != 1 ) {

    #1 is the default account if a ticket is created by a customer
    my $CreatorName = $Self->{AgentUserObject}->UserName(
        UserID => $Param{CreateBy},
    );
    $Self->{LayoutObject}->Block(
        Name => 'Creator',
        Data => { CreatorName => $CreatorName },
    );

}
####### this is the end of the new part #######    
# ticket responsible
if (
    $Self->{ConfigObject}->Get('Ticket::Responsible')
    &&
    $Self->{Config}->{AttributesView}->{Responsible}
    )
{
    my $ResponsibleName = $Self->{AgentUserObject}->UserName(
        UserID => $Param{ResponsibleID},
    );
    $Self->{LayoutObject}->Block(
        Name => 'Responsible',
        Data => { ResponsibleName => $ResponsibleName },
    );
}

# check if ticket is normal or process ticket
```

I used an OTRS 3.3.8+ITSM so your line numbers may vary. The ne inserted Block checks if the creator is != UserID 1 which is the local admin account used by OTRS to created tickets if the creator is not an agent. If its != 1 OTRS performs a lookup an saves the real name in the var. After this, the creator dtl:block gets rendered.

Second part:
Modify your template file:
Copy the original file from Kernel/Output/HTML/Standard/CustomerTicketZoom.dtl to: 
Custom/Kernel/OUTPUT/HTML/Standard/CustomerTicketZoom.dtl

and insert a new block (around L#:190 - after the owner block):

```
<!-- dtl:block:Creator -->
                    <li><span class="Key">$Text{"Creator"}:</span> $QData{"CreatorName"}</li>
<!-- dtl:block:Creator -->
```

After you applied your changes the creator should be shown correctly.